# tkinter button color autochanging

Tags: python, tkinter

```
root = Tk()
root.title('Tic-Tac-Toe by Ahmed')
root.geometry('500x500')

logo = PhotoImage(file = 'download.gif')
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('clam')
print(style.theme_names())
style.configure('TButton', background = 'black', foreground = 'white', font = ('Arial', 30, 'bold'))

ttk.Label(root, text = 'Welcome to Tic-Tac-Toe by Ahmed', background = 'black', foreground = 'red', font = ('Arial',20,'italic'), anchor = 'center')\
.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = 'ew')

playbtn = ttk.Button(root, text = 'Play')
playbtn.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = 'snew')

root.call('wm','iconphoto',root,logo)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight = 1)
root.rowconfigure(1, weight = 2)
root.mainloop()
```

i've tried this code but the button color automatically change when i put the cursor on it, i've also tried to use (activebackground) but it still the same :/ , how to solve that ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to solve? It sounds like the button is doing what it's designed to do.

Comment: You can use `style.map(...)` to change the color of the button when it is in certain state, like `active`, `disabled`, `pressed`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
style.map("TButton", foreground=[('!active', 'white'), ('active', 'white')], background=[('!active', 'red'), ('active', 'red')], font = [('!active', ('Arial', 30, 'bold')), ('active', ('Arial', 30, 'bold'))])
```

it's ok, this code solved the problem ! :)